# Restyling style ( CSS ) definition for the unordered list ( <ul> ) element ( margin inconsistency )

Tags: html, css, html-lists

The example on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FbEXV/

What I've tried to do is restyle my

```
<ul id="options">
            <li>important</li>
            <li>featured</li>
            <li>unanswered</li>
            <li>most_recent</li>
        </ul>
```

To not appear as an unordered list with bullets but rather as tabs. 
Definitions I've used

```
ul
list-style-type:none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

li
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

But this is not enough, the li elements seem to have a right margin of sorts. Can you figure what the problem is ? http://jsfiddle.net/FbEXV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` to your li, that should do the trick

```
li
{
    float:left;
    //Other stuff..
}
```

Comment: Btw, GJ for posting a jsfiddle link, that really helps people to understand the problem you're getting and results in a faster solution!

Answer (score 1):

The space come from  `inline-block` so as rob said it's good to use `float:left` or there is an other option write like this

```
<ul id="options">
            <li>important</li><li>featured</li><li>unanswered</li><li>most_recent</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information. I will sure need it someday.